# how to convert an int array to string in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem in converting an int array into string. Here is my part of code

```
  response_list=[]

  for key in json_response['response_code']:              
        if json_response['response_code'][key] ['0'] is True: 
            print('No such exist')
            response_list.append('Check')
            sys.exit()
```

What happens is this 'response_code' that is part of the output result of my entire code consist of either 0 and 1. So what I want to do is if 'response_code' is 0 in the output result print the needy and exit the whole operation.

I used for but it says 'int is not iterable with for loop. I tried using the dictionary:

```
 response_list=[]

   keydict=str(json_response['response_code'])
    for key in keydict:              
        if keydict == ['0'] is True: 
            print('No such exist')
            response_list.append('Check')
            sys.exit()
```

I still get the int is not iterable

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can someone please explain how to solve the issue

p.s response_list stores the values so I can use later in my code.

What happens in my full code:

I have a list of urls where I want to get it scanned from VirusTotal API. So the API scans the list of urls one by one and if response code = 1 that means API outputs results. If the response code for another url becomes 0 it means  API does not show result

Comment: Putting `is True` on your conditions is a really bad way to write conditions, because of operator chaining.

Comment: Isnt the response code just a number? Why are you trying to iterate through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use a list for the iteration in `For` loop as you are using a `dict` and `string` doesn't work in you case

Trying to Iterate JSON

`for key in json_response['response_code']`

Trying to Iterate String

`for key in str(json_response['response_code'])`

Make sure you are using a valid `list` for the iteration.

Post your `json_response['response_code']` structure if you need any help with the iteration of a specific value in the JSON.

---

`if keydict == ['0'] is True:`

This will not work,
If you want to check a variable

`if keydict == ['0']:`   If you want to check for a specific value

`if keydict:`   if you want to check if the `keydict` has a value

Comment: sorry but I do have another question? the if condition is not working when I use this method

Comment: And what exactly you are trying to do for the `if` condition ??

Comment: Updated the answer please check.

Comment: i am trying to check if response_code=0 then the system should stop. If not, continue

Comment: Can you please attach a sample of your response ?